# Error Building Environment when updating Node.js

Tags: heroku, node.js

When I update node.js to 16.8.0 on an existing program heroku is unable to build the environment and throws the following error:

```
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-uDE+ma9xOMfF4ncJHoymBWA084DqoO8q/hBDvGx4WUxmvFQfHoCsk3BYk1D1Lei/lhNCZXLf1vkeNYVBSqrSgw== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-uDE+ma9xOMfF4ncJHoymBWA084DqoO8q/hBDvGx4WUxmvFQfHoCsk3BYk1D1Lei/lhNCZXLf1vkeNYVBSqrSgw== but got sha512-XL7d6nOKYiv1Q8hQAylQFvnj70V0i+RwIPfLv0IqtR3Q/a6VdRcilffWhL6lzENNdjgkM20PTfy/4RB24jJ1Ug==. (601430 bytes)
```

The program runs without issue locally. Any idea on what I could do to get this issue resolved? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[**Heroku - Cache Behavior**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#cache-behavior)

> Heroku maintains a build cache that is persisted between builds. This
> cache is used to store caches for npm, yarn, and bower.
>
> You can disable all caching for Node.js apps if you prefer:
>
> ```
> heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
> ```

Then, before redeploying try to uninstall/reinstall your package locally:

`npm uninstall package_name`

and then :

`npm install package_name`

Comment: I was able to successfully disable caching however I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: try to uninstall/reinstall the package via npm locally